# Programmatically Alias Method that uses $& Global Variable

Tags: ruby, global-variables, metaprogramming

I'm trying to alias a method that use's Ruby's special `$&` ([returns last regex match](http://jimneath.org/2010/01/04/cryptic-ruby-global-variables-and-their-meanings.html#_dollar_ampersand)). I can do this manually and it works:

```
original = String.instance_method(:sub)
String.send(:define_method, :sub) do |*args, &block|
  puts "called"
  original.bind(self).call(*args, &block)
end
"foo".sub(/f/) { $&.upcase }
  called
  # => "Foo"
```

However if I try to write a method that does this for me, it fails:

```
def programatic_alias(klass, method_name)
  original = klass.instance_method(method_name)
  klass.send(:define_method, method_name) do |*args, &block|
    puts "called"
    original.bind(self).call(*args, &block)
  end
end

programatic_alias(String, :sub)
"foo".sub(/f/) { $&.upcase }
  called
  NoMethodError: undefined method `upcase' for nil:NilClass
  called
  called
  called
    from (irb):19:in `block in irb_binding'
```

It looks like the global state is being affected by the scope of the `programatic_alias` method, but I'm not sure if that's what's going on. The questions is this: how can I programmatically alias `String#sub` so that it still works with Ruby's special global variables?

Comment: What version of ruby are you using? For me with 2.2.1 your example is working.

Comment: I'm using Ruby 2.2.2. You need to make sure you run the examples in different scripts/irb sessions otherwise you might be using the previously defined method alias. I tried on 2.2.1 on my local machine, was able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why would you use the `$&` global variable?

Comment: @hakcho ¯\_(ツ)_/¯  but it's alive in the wild https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb#L73

Comment: I see a easier alternative to your problem that is why I am asking. Besides you can [read](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) it is not accepted as a good practise to use them.

Comment: @hakcho my code needs to alias __ANY__ method, as it's for a library. Re-writing all code in all ruby libraries isn't really an option. I'm interested in a solution to this specific problem, not a workaround.

Comment: Same problem with $1 and $2 variables with gsub etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't do this. The [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html) say

> These global variables are thread-local and method-local variables.

If you dig into the ruby source, accessing `$&` calls [`last_match_getter`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_2/re.c#L1643) which gets its data from [`rb_backref_get`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_2/vm.c#L944), which calls [`vm_svar_get`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_2/vm.c#L930) which (skipping over a few more internal methods) gets the current control frame and reads the data from there. None of this data is exposed to the ruby api - there's no way to propagate this data from one frame to the one you want to access it in.

In your second example the call to the original method is happening inside your `programatic_alias` method, and so `$&` is being set in that scope. For the same reason

```
'foo'.try(:sub, /f/) {$&.upcase}
```

won't work either.

Your first example half works because the place where `sub` is called and the place where `$&` is referenced (inside the block) are in the same method scope (in this case the ruby top level). Change it to:

```
original = String.instance_method(:sub)
String.send(:define_method, :sub) do |*args, &block|
  puts "called"
  original.bind(self).call(*args, &block)
end

def x
  "foo".sub(/f/) { $&.upcase }
end

x()
```

and `$&` is no longer defined in your block (if you catch the exception thrown by `x` you can see that `$&` is being set at the top level)

Comment: Apparently this is a pretty old (known) issue. Here's a thread talking about it from 2009 https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/198458#1174493. Not nearly as detailed as your explanation though, thanks again!