# Get Method Arguments using Ruby's TracePoint

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'm able to get access to a Ruby method's arguments using the TracePoint API:

```
def foo(foo_arg)
end

trace = TracePoint.trace(:call, :c_call) do |tp|
  tp.disable
  case tp.method_id
  when :foo, :sub
    method = eval("method(:#{tp.method_id})", tp.binding)
    method.parameters.each do |p|
      puts "#{p.last}: #{tp.binding.local_variable_get(p.last)}"
    end
  end
  tp.enable
end

trace.enable

foo(10)
# => foo_arg: 10
```

However when I try this with a c method call, I get an error.

```
"foo".sub(/(f)/) { $1.upcase }
script.rb:20:in `method': undefined method `sub' for class `Object' (NameError)
    from script.rb:20:in `<main>'
    from script.rb:8:in `eval'
    from script.rb:8:in `block in <main>'
    from script.rb:20:in `<main>'
```

This looks like it happens because of a discrepancy between the binding returned when using a C method call and regular Ruby method call.

In the Ruby case `tp.self` is equal to `tp.binding.eval("self")` is `main` however in the C case `tp.self` is `"foo"` and `tp.binding.eval("self")` is `main`. Is there a way to get the arguments passed into a method using TracePoint for both Ruby and C defined methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you point in your question and as it documented in [ruby documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/TracePoint.html#method-i-self), `tp.self` returns a traced object, which have a `method` method you are looking for.
I think you should use

`method = tp.self.method(tp.method_id)`

instead of

`method = eval("method(:#{tp.method_id})", tp.binding)`

**UPDATE**. Some explanation regarding your last paragraph in question. `tp.self` in first case (when you call `foo`) is point to `main`, because you define `foo` method in main context and it points to `String` object in second case because `sub` is defined there. But `tp.binding.eval("self")` returns `main` in both cases because it returns a calling context (not a 'define' context as you expect) and in both cases it is `main`.

**UPDATE (in reply to comment)** I think that the only way to do this is to monkey patch `sub` and all other methods that you are interesting for. Code example:

```
class String
  alias_method :old_sub, :sub
  def sub(*args, &block)
    old_sub(*args, &block)
  end
end

trace = TracePoint.trace(:call, :c_call) do |tp|
  tp.disable
  case tp.method_id
  when :sub
    method = tp.self.method(tp.method_id)
    puts method.parameters.inspect
  end
  tp.enable
end

trace.enable

"foo".sub(/(f)/) { |s| s.upcase }
```

One big drawback is that you can't use `$1, $2, ...` vars in your original blocks. As pointed [here](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/198458) where is no way to make it works. However you can still use block parameters (`s` in my example).

Comment: Thanks for the response! That works, however sub only returns `[[:rest]]` for the C parameters and when trying to get `tp.binding.local_variables` for the  I get `[:trace]` which looks like it is coming from the main context. Do you have an idea of how to get around this problem?

Comment: Funny you should mention that as an option. It's why I started using TracePoint in the first place, to work around that problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30512945/programmatically-alias-method-that-uses-global-variable. Unfortunately i'm trying to trace all times `gsub` is called and people definetly use $1 and $2 and they aren't easily replaceable.

Comment: I'm afraid that if you wanna go deeper you will have to deal with making your own C-extension...

Comment: If anyone else is wondering. I did some crazy sh*t to parse the ruby source code since I could easily get the file and line number where it is called. It doesn't work 100% of the time but it is better than not recording any C calls: https://github.com/schneems/let_it_go/blob/13557936b35b59d6b222287fd08d5421ce488f10/lib/let_it_go/method_call.rb#L42 kept an in memory cache of positive hits so we wouldn't have to constantly keep reading in disk. It's a crazy hack, but it mostly works.