# How do I trace where the default logger is being overwritten?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi I have tho follwing line in my `production.rb` file:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT) if defined? Rails::Console
```

This is used to have SQL printed out when using the console in production.

Recently (after I updated some gems i suspect) it stopped working (nothing get's printed anymore).

If I run the line manually in the console after it has started, everything works fine. For this reason, I suspect that some other code somewhere is overwriting the default logger. How can I find out what and where?

I thought about using Tracepoint but not sure how.

Comment: is this deployed to heroku by chance?

Comment: Nope it's on my own servers

Comment: move this code in initializers and name the file something like 0_logger.rb, than who ever is overriding might stop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Method Arguments using Ruby's TracePoint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30584454/get-method-arguments-using-rubys-tracepoint)